# Python Django equals in function arguments. Setting the variable dynamically

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I think this is called "Positional arguments" or the opposite or keyword arguments. I have written a script in Python Django and rest framework that has to take in parameters from the user and feed it to the Amazon API. Here is the code;

```
page = request.query_params.get('page');
search = request.query_params.get('search');
search_field = request.query_params.get('search_field');
search_index = request.query_params.get('search_index');

response = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords=search, SearchIndex=search_index, ResponseGroup="ItemAttributes,Offers,Images,EditorialReview,Reviews")
```

In this code the text `Keywords=search` varies. That is. It could be like this Actor=search, Title=search, or Publisher=search I am not sure how to make the `Keywords` part dynamic such that it changes to the user's input such as Actor, Title, or Publisher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should build up a dictionary of your kwargs and then use the `**` syntax to expand it for the function call.  I'm going give an example that presumes the `search_field` query param changes the search:

```
search = request.query_params.get('search');
search_field = request.query_params.get('search_field');
search_index = request.query_params.get('search_index');

kwargs = {
    'SearchIndex': search_index,
    'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images,EditorialReview,Reviews'
}

# Presuming search_field is the key, i.e. "Keywords", or "Actor"
kwargs[search_field] = search
### kwargs['Keywords'] = search
response = amazon.ItemSearch(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just saw this after answering my own question.

Comment: That's alright, glad you got a solution :)  The `**` expansion trick is very useful for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a dictionary instead. This is how I have done it;

```
    page = request.query_params.get('page');
    search = request.query_params.get('search');
    search_field = request.query_params.get('search_field');
    search_index = request.query_params.get('search_index');

    dict = {'SearchIndex':search_index, 'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images,EditorialReview,Reviews'}
    dict[search_field] = search;
    response = amazon.ItemSearch(**dict)
```

I just passed a dictionary with my dynamic variable as a key.